# how to display (flash?) messages as to the success/types of failure/errors that occur from passport local strategy authentication

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js, ejs

I am following a tutorial on node, express, passport, mongo, EJS, and a few other supporting libraries and concepts.  It walks you through the app, the routes, authentication, and strategies.  You end up with all the CRUD operations of an API and a few unassuming HTML pages to sign up, login, and view entries from the DB.  Here are two snippets that work together:

````
    ```authRouter.route('/signin')
      .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/signin'
      }));```
````

and (true to the documentation) code in the local strategy:

````
    ```if(user) {
      done(null, user);
    } else {
      done(null, false)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    done(error, false);```
````

...that almost literally doesn't do much more than defining the three states a local strategy can produce:  success, failure, and error.  This actually works.  I tested it.  If the user is in the database (and the password checking not shown here passes)...or not...or an exception arises, debugging or developer tools reveal that each of these 3 states occur.  But the only difference you'd see is the redirection that occurs from the options/settings in the second parameter of authenticate.

But a user needs to know more than he/she has just been taken back to the home page or is staying at the login page.  Yes, some of those signatures have overrides or are even open-ended.  You could pass back messages you'd like to the user to see or whole objects that could be the fodder for those messages.  The local strategy snippet could look like this:

````
    ```if ( user ) {
      done(null, user, { message: `You are logged in.  Welcome back ${user.name}.` } );
    } else {
      done(null, false, { message: 'Invalid username/password combination.' } );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    done(error, false, { message: error } );```
````

and the authRouter could be as sophisticated as:

````
```authRouter.route('/signin')
  .post(
    passport.authenticate(
      'local',
      {
        successRedirect: '/',
        successMessage: true,
        successFlash: true,
        failureRedirect: '/auth/signin',
        failureMessage:  true,
        failureFlash: true
      },
      function (err, user, msg) {
        try {
          if (err) {
            //?
          } else {
            if (user) {
              //?
            }```
````

(extra options that don't seem to have an effect and aren't documented very well by passport or blogs/help sites AND a custom callback) but I am still left with the conundrum of what to do with those "//?"s up there.  As far as I know, this is normally where you'd put your res.render or res.redirect and pass extra info to the view that can be picked up with conditional ejs <% ... %>s.  But there is no res or reqs to be had or next()s.  Some sites even want you to install express-flash.  That is supposed to make "messages.error" show up in your <% ... %> checks, but it doesn't.

I just want a little note that ultimately is based on the decision/return values of the local strategy to be able to be bubbled up via the router and get to the HTML page somehow.  I would triple this post length if I included all the googling and demo/example/tutorial reading I've logged.  But this is a basic boilerplate function, right?  All (basic or good) websites have this:  little messages that let you know if you've logged in successfully or if you need to keep trying for some reason or another?  Please smart people of StackOverflow, you're my only hope!

Comment: I found my answer by accident after I had finally given up, decided I needed to work on other aspects of the project and come back to signingin later.  My answer is hybrid of the two extremes I outline above.  I took by route back to:

 authRouter.route('/signin')
   .post(passport.authenticate('local', {
   successRedirect: '/',
   successMessage: true,
   successFlash: true,
   failureRedirect: '/auth/signin',
   failureMessage:  true,
   failureFlash: true
    }
   ));
 
just as arbitrary place to leave the code after I made a back up.  But I left my local strategy as:

Comment: if ( user ) {
          done(null, user, { message: `You are logged in.  Welcome back ${user.name}.` } );
        } else {
          done(null, false, { message: `User, ${user.emailAddress} not found.` } );
        }
      } catch (error) {
        done(error, false, { message: error } );
      }

(with the messages in the third param.)  I honestly expected that to cause more runtime errors and that I'd have shrink the done calls back to two params.

Well surprise surprise I had left:

 app.use(flash());

in my app.js and I had left:

Comment: app.use(flash());

in my app.js and I had left:

 <% if( locals.message ) { %>
  <p><%= locals.message %></p>
 <% } %>
 <% if( messages.error ) { %>
  <p><%= messages.error %></p>
 <% } %>

in my sigin.ejs.  I ran my code one time.  I don't know why.  I didn't expect anything.  I supplied a proper email address and password and as expected I was routed back home.  Sigh I was going to have to live with that until I could find someone to ask about it.  But then I ran my code another time purposely with a bad password and the unsuccessful login appeared in my messages div.

Comment: Ok I guess running flash() causes all pages to be loaded with messages.error.  So I took a guess that there was also a messages.success?  Re-wrote my signin.ejs to:

 <% if ( locals.message ) { %>
  <p><%= locals.message %></p>
 <% } else if (messages.error) { %>  
  <% if ( messages.error ) { %>
   <p><%= messages.error %></p>
  <% } else if (messages.success) {%>
   <p><%= messages.success %></p>
  <% } %>
 <% } %>

Logged in correctly and the messages showed the successful message.  So the lesson learned is never stop guessing.  One day you'll find the undocumented variables.